# The app is blocked in Google Sheet when running a script from App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The app is blocked when running a script from App Script

We have an existing Google sheet that is shared to some of my colleagues, I added an extension called app script, whenever my colleagues try to run the script, after they authorize the app, they are getting error the app is blocked, but when I tried to share the google sheet to my other colleagues, they were able to run the script after authorizing it.

Existing users who have access on the sheet can't run the script, but the recently added users to the sheet can run the script.

Any advice on how to resolve this issue?